# EntityFramework adding nested entities fast

Tags: entity-framework

I have these models in the database. And I have a collection of POCOs representing these models and the relationships. I need to add them to the database and create the relationships between them. All objects count is like 200k. What is the most efficient way to do this ?

```
public class A
{
    private ICollection<B> children;

    public A()
    {
        this.children = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> Children
    {
        get { return this.children; }
        set { this.children = value; }
    }
}

public class B
{
    private ICollection<C> children;

    public B()
    {
        this.children = new HashSet<C>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AId { get; set; }

    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> Children
    {
        get { return this.children; }
        set { this.children = value; }
    }
}

public class C
{
    private ICollection<D> children;

    public C()
    {
        this.children = new HashSet<D>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BId { get; set; }

    public virtual B B { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<D> Children
    {
        get { return this.children; }
        set { this.children = value; }
    }
}

public class D
{
    private ICollection<E> children;

    public D()
    {
        this.children = new HashSet<E>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }

    public virtual C C { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<E> Children
    {
        get { return this.children; }
        set { this.children = value; }
    }
}

public class E
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DId { get; set; }

    public virtual D D { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the fastest way, use raw ADO.NET, even consider using SqlBulkCopy.

You could also consider using TVPs with raw ADO.NET rather than BULK COPY

Comment: I must use EF. I'm trying for each "A" to add all of its children which are "B", for "B" to add all of its children which are "C", until the end of the hierarchy, then when i hit SaveChanges(), I'm getting the error "statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_dbo.E_dbo.D_DId. The conflict occurred in database "TestDatabase", table "dbo.D", column 'Id'."

Comment: If you use IDENTITY columns, you must call SaveChanges to get the database created Id (and possibly wrap the whole thing in a DbTransaction)